# Melting a List in column to multiple rows in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

What I am trying to do is, I have a list of star_cast and list of a genre for a single movie entity. I want to melt this list down as a repeating entity in data frame so that I can store it in a database system.

```
director_name = ['chris','guy','bryan']
genre = [['mystery','thriller'],['comedy','crime'],['action','adventure','sci -fi']]
gross_vlaue = [2544,236544,265888]
imdb_ratings = [8.5,5.4,3.2]
metascores = [80.0,55.0,64.0]
movie_names = ['memento','snatch','x-men']
runtime = [113.0,102.0,104.0]
star_cast = [['abc','ced','gef'],['aaa','abc'],['act','cst','gst','hhs']]
votes = [200,2150,2350]

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({"movie_names":movie_names,
                        "imdb_ratings":imdb_ratings,
                        "metscores":metascores,
                        "votes":votes,
                        "runtime":runtime,
                        "genre":genre,
                        "director_name": director_name,
                        "star_cast": star_cast,
                        "gross_value":gross_vlaue
                       })
```

The above will generate a Data Frame sample I have.

```
director_name = ['chris','chris','chris','chris','chris','chris','guy','guy','guy','guy','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan','bryan']
genre = ['mystery','thriller','mystery','thriller','mystery','thriller','comedy','crime','comedy','crime','action','adventure','sci -fi','action','adventure','sci -fi','action','adventure','sci -fi','action','adventure','sci -fi']
gross_vlaue = [2544,2544,2544,2544,2544,2544,236544,236544,236544,236544,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888,265888]
imdb_ratings = [8.5,8.5,8.5,8.5,8.5,8.5,5.4,5.4,5.4,5.4,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2,3.2]
metascores = [80.0,80.0,80.0,80.0,80.0,80.0,55.0,55.0,55.0,55.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0,64.0]
movie_names = ['memento','memento','memento','memento','memento','memento','snatch','snatch','snatch','snatch','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men','x-men']
runtime = [113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,113.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,102.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0,104.0]
star_cast = ['abc','ced','gef','abc','ced','gef','aaa','abc','aaa','abc','act','cst','gst','hhs','act','cst','gst','hhs','act','cst','gst','hhs']
votes = [200,200,200,200,200,200,2150,2150,2150,2150,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350,2350]

sample_result = pd.DataFrame({"movie_names":movie_names,
                        "imdb_ratings":imdb_ratings,
                        "metscores":metascores,
                        "votes":votes,
                        "runtime":runtime,
                        "genre":genre,
                        "director_name": director_name,
                        "star_cast": star_cast,
                        "gross_value":gross_vlaue
                       })
```

This will generate the format I want to conver my data into.

I tried using melt() but no luck there. Please help, as to how it can be achieved in an effective way. My dataset is fairly large, using for loops will be very slow. Is there any other way around solving this?

Comment: Not seeing any actual code here.

Comment: When you run the code above, you get the two sample data frames. the first data frame is the data frame format I have, and the second one is the data frame format I need. I do not know how to go about it!

Comment: That's sort of my point. You haven't actually made an attempt, which is not really supported here. Make a legitimate effort first, don't just ask for free code.